# Strongly-typed boxed values in .NET

Tags: .net, clr, boxing

To box a value type you cast it to `System.Object` - that in itself seems "wrong" to me (because casting should either convert the value to another type (so converting an Int32 to Object should be a data-lossy action, as Object has no instance state of its own) or converting an interface pointer to a parent (which does not affect the state of the object being pointed to and is a compile-time concern). When boxing a value-type in the CLR you're copying the value to the heap and losing interface information at the same time, when you only really want to perform the first task (copying the value to the heap, or at least getting a reference to it).

Java solves this problem with the strong types of `Integer` and `Long`. Why doesn't .NET have this?

I have my own collection of utility source code that I like to include in other projects, and they include their own implementations of strongly-typed boxed classes (such as BoxedInt32) which override the implicit and explicit conversion operators so they work the same way as casting to Object does, except without having to actually cast to object (thus preserving type data). So I can do this:

```
private BoxedInt32 _reference;
public Int32 GetValue{ return _reference; }
```

So why doesn't .NET, after four major releases, still not have strongly-typed boxed types?

Comment: The biggest use case for boxing was for collections and generics solved much of this. Can you say more about the reason why you need these strongly-typed boxed types?

Comment: @akton When values are shared by multiple components of a program but exist outside of static class state then each program component needs a reference to the holding object, which can muddy code when all you need is a reference to that value. `ref` parameters only solve this problem when said program component doesn't need to store that reference in its own state.

Comment: What is you think would be different in your BoxedInt32 vs just an object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There would be no point. You would never directly use BoxedInt32, since if you knew the type in advance it would only be sensible to use `int` instead of the box. So the only interesting case is: when we *don't* know the type in advance, i.e. when dealing with `object`. Well, value-type boxing already handles that perfectly, reporting the type as `Int32`.

The reason the specific boxed versions exist in Java is, in part, because Java generics work very differently via type erasure; however .NET has true generics including for value-types, so this is unnecessary.

You could make your own box:

```
public class Box<T> where T : struct {
    private readonly T value:
    public Box(T value) { this.value = value; }
    public T Value { get { return value; } }
}
```

(perhaps adding more features such as conversions / equality): but - again: no point whatsoever. Regular inbuilt boxing already handles this much better.

Comment: For structure types which implement mutating interfaces (e.g. `List<string>.Enumerator`), there is a difference between casting to the struct type versus performing actions upon the boxed structure. If structs could define custom boxing and unboxing methods (with the provisos that the return type of the boxing method must implement all the interfaces that the struct does, and must be accepted as the parameter for the unboxing method) such issues could be handled nicely. From a CLR perspective, that wouldn't seem hard--just have the JITter check every time it sees a `box` instruction...

Comment: ...whether the type implements the appropriate boxing method (use default boxing if not), and have it check when it sees an `unbox` whether a custom operator is defined.

Comment: It would help with a couple problems in the unified object model.  Under the present implementation, boxed structs which implement mutating interfaces cannot very well obey the `Object.Equals` contract (distinct instances should report unequal regardless of field contents).  Also, some structs which encapsulate particular classes would be more helpfully boxed as the classes they encapsulate than as themselves (a default-valued struct, unlike a default-valued class instance, can offer useful instance methods, but wrapping a class in a struct causes an extra level of boxing.

Comment: @supercat I don't agree that these are problems that need solving. If you want custom boxing, write a ToObject() method and call it. Everything else you mention seems a solution looking for a problem.

Comment: Actually, what might perhaps be more helpful would be if one could simply specify that a structure not be eligible for 'normal' boxing, and that the compiler should reject boxing conversions but allow implicit conversions to `Object` or interfaces.  Unfortunately, that would completely break generics.  Also, another pattern I'd like to see facilitated would be 'ephemeral structs' which could be returned by properties or methods, with implicit conversions to normal types.  Those could be very useful with fluent interfaces.  For example, given `foo = foo.WithX(5).WithY(6).WithZ(7)`, a normal...

Comment: ...implementation would have to create a new object at each stage; if each stage could instead return an 'ephemeral struct' which encapsulated an object type, and featured a widening conversion to the encapsulated object type, the `With` methods on the struct could mutate and return the encapsulated object (since it would hold the only reference to it).  Before the days of type inference, one could name the encapsulated object something like `DoNotCreateVariablesOfThisType` to discourage anyone from persisting the result of `WithX` without converting to the base type.

Comment: Wrapping class items in structures would sometimes be a convenient way of establishing a `default(T)` that can do something useful, but it adds an extra level of boxing and indirection if the structure is cast to an interface, which seems a bit icky.  As for `Equals`, I really don't know any way to make a struct that implements a mutating interface do a decent job of obeying the `Equals` contract when boxed.  I can kludge a solution, but I would think it would be cleaner to have a cast from e.g. `List<T>.Enumerator` to `IEnumerator<T>` yield a class-object that implements `IEnumerator<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

The root of your problem seems like a misunderstanding about how casting works and what it is for:

> (because casting should either convert the value to another type ...  or converting an interface pointer to a parent)

All that happens when you cast one thing to another is to tell the compiler "Please treat this random collection of bits in a slightly different way". The bits are never supposed to get converted or modified at all.
C# and Java throw a type-check in for safety, but that's not central to the casting operation itself.

It's nonsensical to treat the collection of bits that represent an int32 as something else (eg an Object reference), so the Boxing system goes behind your back and generates a wrapper for you. It's still following the rules of casting - the compiler can now treat this boxing wrapper as an Object reference, and the original bits don't get modified

> ... except without having to actually cast to object (thus preserving type data)...

Again, this is based on an incorrect assumption. In line with the explanation above, casting does "preserve type data" by virtue of the fact that it doesn't modify the value, it just changes the way the compiler is interpreting that data. The wrappers generated by boxing still have access to the underlying data, - You can call .GetType() on a boxed int and it will happily report that it's an Int32. 
Your `BoxedInt32` class is just wasting time and space storing data that's already available.

**Note: Sometimes code that looks like casting in C# will actually convert the data by way of calling an implicit conversion operator. This isn't casting, it's just pretending, so the rules don't apply.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be handy for this case:

```
var myDictionary = new Dictionary<int, bool>();

// So we could use a BoxedBool here and modify the
// value set below.
//var myDictionary = new Dictionary<int, BoxedBool>();

myDictionary.Add(1, true);
myDictionary.Add(2, false);

foreach (var key in myDictionary.Keys)
{
    myDictionary[key] = false;
    // Cannot do this as it modified the collection.
    // If it was a reference type, this would not be a problem?
}
```